# Free space after the first few words of a text

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have some free space after the first few words of a text. The following code does not do what I want but hopefully shows you guys what I mean. One reason for not working is that the `span` tag should be converted to `display:block`. But in this case the text followed by the `span` tag would start in the next line but I want it to start in the same line only 25em away from the left border.

```
<span style="width:25em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span> consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
```

Comment: did you try `display: inline-block`?

Comment: I guess a patchwork fix could be a few non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp`) but CSS has got to be the way to do it.  `inline-block` might work.

Comment: you probably want `margin-right`

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your spans:

```
display:inline-block;
margin-right:10em;
```

Or you could wrap the text you want to have an indent in front of it with `<p></p>` tags for example, and apply this css to the p tags:

`text-indent:10em;`

Or you could also manually add spaces before or after text with `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

U can use

```
&nbsp
```

in your html code after the text where you need spaces.

U can use

```
<br/>
```

to get stared from the next line.
 I hope you got the answer.

Comment: entities should end with semicolons; self-closing tags don't need slashes outside of XHTML

Comment: doesn't help with responsiveness, op wants 25em space

Answer (score 0):

Just add {display:inline-block}

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25em; 
}


<p><span>Lorem Ipsum</span> Dolor Sit Amet</p>
```

in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2TW8N/1/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. This helped me to find the solution for my problem. An inline-block is what I was looking for.

```
<span style="display:inline-block;width:25em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span> consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
```